# AngularJS - Trying to have widget header show - not working

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to work out the widget feature, however I'm unable to get this working as expected. This is my header as of now:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
   <div class="widget-header">
        <span class="widget-caption header-title"> User Groups </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

It's actually been irritating since I'm unsure what I've been doing wrong, all I want is the default widget shown here:
http://beyondadmin-v1.6.0.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/widgets.html

Comment: you don't have a bg-color, do you even have the CSS loaded

Comment: What exactly is not as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you've referred the stylesheets of `Beyond` template.

[image]

```html
<!-- Beyond styles -->
<link href="assets/css/beyond.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The location of **href** may vary according to your folder structure.

Ref URL: http://apps-empresariales.com/conta/dev/docs/